# How to open multiple files whose name has a special characters in it in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

I have a list which has contain the names of all the files present in a directory. The name of the files has a special characters in it. For example:- 'MDH'_data_dump.csv, 'PLD'_data_dump.csv etc ( single quotes ).  I am trying to run a loop through a list which will open all the csv file, append the data for all the csv files into a single dataframe . But I am getting an error. I am able to open one file at a time like this

```
recon_dataframe=pd.read_csv('\'BAL\'_data_dump.csv')
```

And this is working perfectly fine. But how to run through a loop for all the files, I am unable to get the logic. Please help . The code that I tried was :

```
recon_dataframe=pd.DataFrame()
  for i in range(0,len(csv_files)):
    recon_dataframe.append(pd.read_csv(csv_files[i][:5]+csv_files[i][5:]))
```

***csv_files is the list which has all the names of the list.***
 Moreover the name of all the files are in similar format. String after the quotes are constant and the only portion that varies is the string within the quotes

Comment: why dont u escape the quotes in the loop? Seems to be the solution.

Comment: WHAT error do you get? Please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: note sure if it is your problem here, but the `append` method on dataframe does not work as with `list`, you need to reassign it:. So in your loop it should be `recon_dataframe = recon_dataframe.append(...`. For efficiency, see at the bottom of this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and use `concat`

Comment: Hi Ben , You got it right. Once I reassigned ,the code worked. I did not knew this concept before. Thanks for prompt reply. I also figure it out in slight different way to deal with such problem which I feel is quite robust. I am posting the answer below. Thank you once again and be safe :)

Answer (score 1):

I did in this way and got the answers.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
for j in csv_files:
    p=j[1:4]
    df=pd.read_csv('\'{}\'_F47072_data_dump.csv'.format(p))
    df1=pd.concat([df,df1])
```

Edit: The proper way to use `concat` here would be:

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('\'{}\'_F47072_data_dump.csv'.format(j[1:4]))
                 for j in csv_files])
```

although that the order might be different in the result, but it would be faster

Comment: I added the proper way to use `concat` with your example, hope it makes sense (and works)  using concat (or append) for each iteration in a for loop will be really slow if you have a lot of iteration or the data is big

Comment: Also, you should accept your own answer to close the question, if someone add a better answer latter on, you can still change the accepted answer at this time.